# A user in a UserList of a chat Application, getting the wrong CSS value. (Jquery + socketio)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, socket.io

I am trying out a feature for a chat Application where it contains a user list,who have joined that chat. When a particular users gets disconnected/leaves the chat, the color of the particular user should change in the list (i.e if andy,rubin are two members and rubin leaves his name should reflect with a color while andy's name shoudnt change color). My problem is that if a person leaves i am getting that color to reflect on all the members in the list (i.e both andy and rubin are getting a change in color if any one of them leaves)

**server.js**

```
socket.on('disconnect',function(data){
    console.log('user disconnected');
    if(!socket.nickname)   
         return;
      socket.broadcast.emit('userDisconnect',{nick:socket.nickname});  
})
```

**chat.js**

```
socket.on('userDisconnect',function(data){
    //  var str = [];
    // str.push(data.nick)
    // for(var i= 0;i<data.length;i++){
    //  str = data.nick[i]
    //  }
    //  $users.text(data.nick).css("color","red")   //disconnected user is only reflected on the list,rest of them vanish
    $users.val(data.nick).css("color","red")
})
```

note: I tried some other things that are reflected in the commented part of the code

I expected only a particular user is the list should change the color when he leaves but the actual value is that all of them are getting the color when any user leaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for jQuery `val()`, it says:

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

https://api.jquery.com/val/

So basically what you're doing, you're setting the value for all the users as `data.nick`. Same goes for the `text()` method.

It's better to match user by id, which could be the user's nickname in this case, but for that you need to assign that id when you're rendering the users.
Then you can do something like this:

```
socket.on('userDisconnect',function(data){
    $(`#id_${data.nick}`).css("color","red")
})
```

Comment: I realized that now. I am  a bit confused on the changes to be done. Does changes should be made on the client side code or the server side code

Comment: Depends how are you rendering your user list. If it's server side, the changes should be made there.

Comment: can you please have a look at it,this is the server code **socket.on('new user',function(data,callback){
            callback(true);
            socket.nickname=data; 
            name=socket.nickname;              
           users[name] = socket;             
         io.sockets.emit('usernames',Object.keys(users));
    });**

Comment: client code,            **socket.on('usernames',function(data){
                var str=' ';
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    str+=data[i]+'<br/>';
                }
                $users.html(str).css("color","black");
            });**

Comment: You can use JS template interpolation to add your html:socket.on('usernames', function(data) {
  var str = ' ';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    str += ``<p id="#id_${data[i]}">${data[i]}</p>``;
  }
  $users.html(str).css("color", "black");
})

Comment: the modification is giving this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < , i have the client code in a chat.js file which i linked to the index.html file.

Comment: I think the code highlight removed the backticks around ` <p id="#id_${data[i]}">${data[i]}</p> `

Comment: I am not getting any error but the change is not getting reflected, the user is not getting the color in the list.